# How can i play music using QByteArray data?

Tags: qt, qt5, qbytearray, qmediaplayer

I have a QByteArray which created like this:

```cpp
QByteArray data;
QFile file("/path/to/music.mp3");

if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    data = file.readAll();
}
```

And i get it somewhere else, how could i play it using `QMediaPlayer` without save it to file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **.mp3** file directly, you can call it by directly setting the **URL** to QMediaPlayer.

You can find below example in documentation.

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;
connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), this, SLOT(positionChanged(qint64)));
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/path/to/music.mp3"));
player->setVolume(50);
player->play();
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#setMedia

If for obvious reasons, you have to go with `QByteArray`, May be you can try as said below (Not tried and tested):

```
//BYTE ARRAY
QByteArray data;
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    data = file.readAll();
}

//CREATE A BUFFER OBJECT WITH BYTE ARRAY
QBuffer buffer(&data);
buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

//CREATE MEDIA PLAYER OBJECT
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;

//SET MEDIA CONTENT AND BUFFER.
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/path/to/music.mp3"),&buffer);
player->play();
```

Comment: Thank you, but i don't have any file to mentioned in the first argument of `setMedia()` function.